# Is there a way to define group of test classes to run under same Gradle JVM fork?

Tags: gradle, jvm, build.gradle, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have a set of **Spring Boot integration tests** I am trying to optimise. For that I was trying to leverage the [Application Context caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching), however in the docs it says, as it is being stored in a static variable, that when using the **Gradle forked JVMs** test execution this won't be used as effectively.

So I was wondering if there is a way to somehow define what group of test classes Gradle should run under the **same** fork; for example the ones that could share the same `@WebMvcTest` sliced context.

E.g. Having these test classes:

```
- ATest
- BTest
- CTest
```

I’d like to specify something like:

```
- Fork 1:
  - ATest
  - BTest

- Fork 2:
  - CTest
```

I only found that the **JUnit Platform** provides [Tags annotations](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-tagging-and-filtering) to logically group tests and then include/exclude them in the Gradle Test task config; but I didn't found if it could be used with the forking somehow.

Is there a way to achieve this with either Gradle or Junit config? (or even maybe with multiple Gradle Test task that I could run in parallel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't configure it explicitly, Gradle will only do one fork.
If you want to fork into multiple test workers, then afair you cannot control which test goes where.

But yes, you could configure multiple tasks that all just do one fork and control for example using tags which task runs which tests.

Another possibility would be to use a JUnit Platform engine that supports parallel test execution. Spock and Jupiter for example both support that, so your test can leverage your multi-processors and run in parallel while staying within one JVM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have another question regarding the option of multiple test tasks, that maybe you can also help me with. 
How would I enable the forking/parallel execution? As I understand this JVM forking is just configurable at an individual task level (involving only the classes defined in that group), and Gradle doesn't allow parallel task execution for one project, right? 

Comment: Please don't ask additional questions in comments but create new questions. For parallel execution of tasks within one project you need to use the configuration cache. Without you would need to have the tasks in different projects and use parallel mode.

Comment: My bad, thanks for the answer and sorry! ‍♂️